# how do i convert from angular1 to 2

Tags: angularjs

[How to do validation in angularjs using invalid and pristine? Also how to do service calls in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254767/how-to-do-validation-in-angularjs-using-invalid-and-pristine-also-how-to-do-ser)

Comment: Not clear to me! Clarify the question, expected output current output, error if anything?

Answer (score 0):

To help with the post caption question "how do I convert from angular1 to 2":

First, regarding the framework names (as per [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)):

> Angular is the name for the Angular of today and tomorrow.  AngularJS
>   is the name for all 1.x versions of Angular.

Angular has a guide that aims to help to with the *conversion*

[Angular - Upgrading from AngularJS](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)

I don't believe there's any one-click converter from AngularJS to Angular

As to the link that you've posted to another post in stackoverflow - not sure what you're asking. :)